# How to replace url with link to that url in post with Flask?

Tags: python, hyperlink, flask, content-management-system

How can I use Python and Flask to insert a link in a post if there is one.

For example if someone puts "google.com" in their post how can I then make that a link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using jinja2 as your templating system, you can use the built in urlize filter which will convert all urls in some text to html link tags:

```
{{ mytext|urlize(40, true) }}
links are shortened to 40 chars and defined with rel="nofollow"
```

It has numerous useful options you can read about in the docs:

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#list-of-builtin-filters

If you are using some other templating engine, they probably have something similar.

If you want to do it client side there is a good discussion of all your options here:

[How to replace plain URLs with links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links#21925491)

Comment: Is there a way to do something like this to tag Users with @?

Comment: It's probably pretty easy to do a match on @something in a string. What do you want the link to look like? A link to Twitter? Just write a filter.

Comment: As you can probably tell, I'm pretty new to this stuff. How would I go about writing a filter? Thank You for the help!

Comment: I suppose you could ask a new question. But you could also look at the docs. It's pretty easy.http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/templating/